# ََUnequivocal usage of "their"

Tags: usage, possessives

Consider the following castes:

- Ali has a  house in Tehran. John has a house in Paris.
- Ali has two houses in Tehran. John has two houses in Paris.
- Ali and John share a house in Paris.
- Ali and John share two houses in Paris.

Which of the following sentences could follow each of above sentences:

- Their house is big.
- Their houses are big.

Similarly, what does this sentence implies: "Their cars are clean":
Each one has one or more cars or there are some cars that belonged to all.

Comment: I think we should use the plural form when there is more than one house. So 1, 2, 4 use *their houses are big*. The only thing the sentence conveys is the number, that *overall* there is more than one house. *Their cars are clean* can mean either *each has one or more car* or *there are some cars that belonged to all.*

Answer (score 2):

"Their house is big." canNOT be used distributively.  In other words, that sentence cannot mean that *"they each have a house, and each house is big."  Instead it can only mean "They share/live in/own a house, and it is big."

On the other hand, "Their houses are big" CAN be used distributively OR collectively.  "Their houses are big" means "They each have a house, and each house is big." OR "They share/live in/own multiple houses, and those houses are big."